# Gin & Tonics vs Gins & Tonic vs Gins & Tonics

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

When I order multiple G&Ts which should I ask for?

Answer (score 9):

I always ask for "Gin and tonics". Complex phrases used as proper nouns are always a little complicated, but in most cases we treat the entire phrase as a noun an attach the plural *-s* to the final element. This is true even in the case where the final element isn't even a noun, as in the sentence "Do six sit-ups".

Answer (score 4):

A gin and tonic is a drink with the gin and the tonic already mixed. It's one thing, so "gin and tonics" is correct.

If you ask for "three gins and tonics" it sounds like you want three glasses of gin plus some bottles of tonic water.

If you ask for "three gins and tonic" it sounds like you want three glasses of gin plus one bottle of tonic water.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers may be correct if the bar serving the beverage is in the US or a Mediterranean country such as Italy. In fact the cocktail is probably served already pre-mixed in the glass. I say *probably* because I have never ordered a G&T in Italy. However, when ordering multiple Gs&Ts in the UK the correct way of asking is:

- **Three gins and tonics**

The barman will serve the client three glasses of gins and three small bottles of tonic water (to allow each person to add the quantity of tonic to gin that is their preference).

[Introduction to the British Pub](http://gouk.about.com/od/restaurantandpubguides/a/How-To-Order-A-Beer_2.htm)

> If you ask for a mixed drink - a G&T for example, you'll get a measure
>   of gin in a glass, a small bottle of tonic water and a slice of lemon
>   or lime. You then mix in as much tonic as you like and add ice cubes
>   from the bucket on the counter.

Answer (score 1):

It should be three gins and tonic. That’s because you are asking for gins WITH tonic. The tonic is a mere appendage to the main noun: gin. “He is rich: he owns three houses with a stable” - each house has a stable. Three houses with stables can imply that each house has more than one stable.